# Trying to convert PHP hash_hmac with multiple XOR components to coldfusion

Tags: php, coldfusion

I have been given the unenviable task of converting an old set of PHP pages to ColdFusion. My PHP knowledge is not that great, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to replicate the following line into ColdFusion:

```
$fingerprint = hash_hmac("md5", $loginID . "^" . $sequence . "^" . $timeStamp . "^" . $amount . "^", $transactionKey);
```

The values being passed for each variable are a mix of numbers, letters and decimals.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? When translating an unfamiliar language I find a good place to start is with the documentation for that function: [hash_hmac()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php). It explains it "Generate[s] a keyed hash value using the HMAC method". Then search the CF docs by category for a similar function. For example, the phrase *coldfusion functions by category hash HMAC* returns the documentation for the [HMAC function](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-h-im/hmac.html). The rest is just testing.

Answer (score 4):

ColdFusion alternative for PHP `hash_hmac` is [`hmac()`](https://cfdocs.org/hmac) with `HMACMD5` as algorithm equivalent to `md5` in PHP. Also you might want to do a [`lcase()`](https://cfdocs.org/lcase) call to make the result lower case as CF gives an all capitalized result.

```
<cfscript>
    message = loginID & "^" & sequence & "^" & timeStamp & "^" & amount & "^";
    fingerprint=lcase(hmac(message, transactionKey, "HMACMD5"));
</cfscript>
```

[**DEMO**](https://www.trycf.com/gist/5278ef1b7f9dd99b78a9737a39f8891b/acf2016?theme=monokai)

Comment: @kremer - *"multiple XOR components.."*  ... also notice there's no [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) involved? The php code concatenates a bunch of string variables together, separated by the character literal `^`.

Comment: I owe you steak and scotch. Thank you much for the fast response.

Comment: If you're modifying this code anyway, you may want to go with a stronger hashing algorithm than MD5. But it really depends on what you are using this for and how strong you need your auth to be.